# Pop-up Scope to contain current tab URL on open

Tags: crossrider

I've been using Crossrider's great API for some time now, however I have reached a great block in my progress.

I have been able to message the popup scope with the current domain through the tab change interrupts and the change of url interrupts. However, when I click the popup browser button, data about the current tab URL is supposed to be shown. Instead, such data is black, and when debugging - it was found that the reason for it being blank is either:

- The current URL is being set to the popup extension internal URL
- Some sort of bug with the popup logic

I am really stumped, and require such functionality to progress further. My Crossrider ID is 52909.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, when posting questions to this forum **please include code snippets for the benefit of others so that they can try an assist you**. As-is they have no access to the extension code you provided.

Looking at your popup.html code, I can see that you are using the following Crossrider API methods that are not supported in the popup scope: [appAPI.resources.includeJS](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources-method-includeJS), [appAPI.webRequest.onRequest](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.webRequest.onRequest). For more information about API supported in the popup scope, see [appAPI.browserAction.setPopup](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction).

As alternatives/workarounds:

- For appAPI.resources.includeJS, you can use the jquery to load resources scripts, as follows: `$.globalEval(appAPI.resources.get('script.js'));`
- For appAPI.webRequest.onRequest, implement it in the background scope and use messaging to pass the data to the popup scope, something like:

**background.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(fucntion($) {
  appAPI.webRequest.onRequest.addListener(function(details, opaqueData) {
    appAPI.message.toPopup(details);
  }, []);
});
```

*crossriderMain* in **popup.html**:

```
function crossriderMain($) {
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(details) {
    // Do something with the details from webRequest
  });
}
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]